# Why is liquibase deleting databasechangelog rows and trying to create a renamed database table?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am using postgres 10.5 and liquibase 3.6.2 on a Mac.
I nuke & re-create my database, run liquibase update, and it works.
But a second liquibase update fails with an exception that the pkey already exists.

After the first liquibase update, the databasechangelog table contains 97 entries. After the second, it contains 10, and the time and deployment ids for those are different than they were after the first update!

Table foo was created in an early change.
Later it was changed to be named bar, but the pkey is still foo.pkey.
Liquibase-update should not be trying to re-create foo, but it does, and fails because foo.pkey already exists.

A) In general, how can I get liquibase to output more info about what it's doing?  I tried both of the commands:

```
 liquibase --logLevel=debug --logFile=`pwd`/foo.log update
 liquibase --logLevel debug --logFile `pwd`/foo.log update
```

Both seem to work the same, and foo.log isn't created and there's no more output in the terminal.

B) How can I stop liquibase from trying to re-make this and nuking my databasechangelog?

I tried to make a small example that fails, but this seems to work... Others here are using it with postgres 9.5.10 with no problem...

All I see in the terminal is:

```
Starting Liquibase at Wed, 14 Nov 2018 13:06:44 PST (version 3.6.2 built at 2018-07-03 11:28:09)
Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: relation "cant_change_pkey" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE nuss.cant_change (message_id UUID NOT NULL, origin VARCHAR(4), type VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT CANT_CHANGE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (message_id), UNIQUE (message_id))]
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/changelog-new1.xml::first-one::rstrauss:
 Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "cant_change_pkey" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE nuss.cant_change (message_id UUID NOT NULL, origin VARCHAR(4), type VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT CANT_CHANGE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (message_id), UNIQUE (message_id))]
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:637)
at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:53)
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:78)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1205)
at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:191)
at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:129)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "cant_change_pkey" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE nuss.cant_change (message_id UUID NOT NULL, origin VARCHAR(4), type VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT CANT_CHANGE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (message_id), UNIQUE (message_id))]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:356)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:57)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:125)
at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1229)
at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1211)
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:600)
... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "cant_change_pkey" already exists
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2476)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2189)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:301)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:287)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:264)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:260)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:352)
... 12 common frames omitted
```

For more information, please use the --logLevel flag

Comment: Could you provide scripts you use?

Comment: A) No- it doesn't matter. Others use the same scripts with no problem. How could it POSSIBLY nuke the old changelog rows in the table???